# Is there a way to synchronize several folders data on dropbox to a single folder?

Tags: dropbox

I have several folders under Dropbox and it hasn't been synchronized for a while. Is there a way to synchronize data only on a single folder?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is exactly what you are asking, but in Dropbox preferences, in the Advanced Tab, there is a "Selective Sync..." button. You can then choose which folders to sync.

Have a look [here](https://www.dropbox.com/help/175/en) for reference.